# What is a way to find a discord channel based on what it start with?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to figure out if a discord channel starts with the username of a discord account. I am also using their discriminator. I am using discord.js version 13.8.1.

I have tried to use the .find function but it is not seeming to work. I can't really think of another way to get this to work. I want the if function to run if there is a channel that has the user's username at the start of a channel name.

My current code:

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('851952021505441812');

if(guild.channels.cache.find(
        (channel) => channel.name.startsWith(message.author.tag)
       )){
        return message.reply("Lol")
    }
```

Comment: Does my answer below solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord channels cannot contain the hashtag character `#`, so it is impossible that any channel could start with a user's tag in the format of `username#0000`.

The easiest way to get around this would be to just remove all non-alphanumeric characters from `message.author.tag` and make all channel names that should be searched be in the format of `username0000`, then search for channels that start with that string, like this:

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('...');
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(chan =>
    chan.name.startsWith(message.author.tag.replace('#', '')));
if (channel) {
    // ...
}
```

Also, note that hashtags are not the only restricted character. You may want to further restrict any character that is not alphanumeric.

Another approach would be to ditch the discriminator altogether. This will not only make the code a bit simpler but also future-proof, as [Discord is transitioning to unique usernames](https://discord.com/blog/usernames) that don't have discriminators.